# .Net track changes when DataGridView is bound to List

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a .Net 4.0 Winforms application that has a DataGridView bound to a List(of Object).

I need to implement change tracking of some kind so that when the user edits the data in the grid view, I can determine which objects in the list have been modified.

What I'm looking for is the most lightweight way of tracking changes to the list items. I have a lot of DataGridViews and a lot of Lists in the application. Many of the List objects have a lot of properties so I want to avoid bloat and have the code as clean as possible.

In an older implementation of the application we used DataSets and had tables bound to the DataGridViews. This was fine because we could get RowState from the underlying DataTables. Presumably DataGridViews alone do not maintain any kind of state tracking information I could get at?

At the moment I'm considering implementing IChangeTracking on the objects in my List, but would appreciate your thoughts in case I have missed an already implemented means of tracking changes in Lists that are bound to DataGridViews.

The code I'm using is similar to the following:

```
Private Class MyData
    Public Data1 As String
    Public Data2 As String
End Class

Private Sub DoStuff()
    Dim MyList As New List(Of MyData)

    MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyList
    MyDataGridView.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "Data1"
    MyDataGridView.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Data2"
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly how are they bound? Could you give some idea of the code? If you just want the very basic changes, why not keep a copy of the original Datatable/datasource of the DataGridView and then reference that when need be later on?

Comment: sparkysword I've added a code sample to the question. I'm not binding to a Datatable, I'm binding to a List(of Object).  I could keep a reference to the original list by copying it, but I'd have to iterate through the original and new lists to see what's changed between the two. This would be clunky.

Comment: So, you're telling me you want to record every single change made. What's the goal of that? I feel like you might have a lot of extra data that you'll end of never using.

Comment: Users will edit data in the DataGridView, the edits they make end up in the List (via the bindings). The List data ends up stored in a database, so I need to know which rows they have edited when I go to save the data back to the database. I don't need to track every edit they make, at a minimum knowing which row has been modified will suffice.

Comment: I take it that this is for changes to the list items (as opposed to adding and deleting items)?  A List is already suboptimal for that.  I would think a `DataTable` would be easier than even `IChangeTracking `